# Is client-client communication possible in a fork-based server?

Tags: c, sockets, fork

I am implementing a very basic C server that allows clients to chat. Right now I am using fork(), but I am having trouble having clients see each others' messages.

It also seems that all clients get the same file descriptor from accept(). Basically, I have a while loop where I test if someone wants to connect with select(), accept() their connection, and fork(). After that I read input and try to pass them to all users (whom I am keeping in a list). I can copy/paste my code if necessary.

So, is it possible to have the clients communicate with processes, or do I have to use pthreads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) -IPC- (in general) don't care about client vs server (except at `connect` phase). A given process can have both a client and a server role (on different sockets), and would use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) or the older `select` on several sockets in some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop).

Notice that [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) have each their own [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), while [threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) share the *same* virtual address space (the one of their containing process). Read some [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/), and some book on POSIX programming (perhaps the old [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/%7Ehungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf)). Be aware that a lot of information regarding processes can be queried on Linux thru `/proc/` (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for more). In particular, the virtual address space of process of pid 1234 can be obtained thru `/proc/1234/maps` and its opened file descriptors thru `/proc/1234/fd/` and `/proc/1234/fdinfo/` etc....

However, it is simpler to code a common server keeping the shared state, and dispatching messages to clients.

You could design a protocol where the clients have some way to initiate that IPC. For example, if all the processes are on the same machine, you could have a protocol which transmits a file path used as [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) socket address, or as [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html), and each "client" process later initiate (with some `connect`) a direct communication with another "client". It might be unwise to do so.

Look also into libraries like [0mq](http://zeromq.org/). They often are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), so you can study their source code.

Comment: Yeah, I don't exactly like the idea of direct client-client communication while I already have a list of all clients on the server. I guess pthreads it is...

Comment: I know it can be done with pthreads, but was wondering if possible with processes as well. It's just a local chat server.

Comment: Yes, you can either use threads or processes. But the programming model is *very* different.

Comment: I just had an idea that might be genius: can I manipulate the file descriptor returned from accept() to a value I want? I can add it with the process id from fork() and get a unique file descriptor for each user!

Comment: Be careful (and perhaps more modest) about genial ideas... A file descriptor is some abstract data type (internally represented as some small non-negative integer).

Comment: You're right. I have implemented a pthread solution for my purpose, but I think your suggestions answer my question so I'll checkmark it. Thank you.